# Two xml results in one column

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, xpath

How do i get two xml results in one column as output. Now i get for evru output an column.

```
pub += '<td valign="top" class="col1">' + roepnaam + '</td>' + '\n';    
pub += '<td valign="top" class="col2">' + naamMedewerker + '</td>' + '\n';
```

Can anyone help em out. I want those together. I tried this:

```
pub += '<td valign="top" class="col1">' + roepnaam + + naamMedewerker + '</td>' + '\n';
```

But didn't work. Please help me out?

Comment: Try this: `' + roepnaam + naamMedewerker + '` - just one `+` sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: Remove `+`

```
 pub += '<td valign="top" class="col1">' + roepnaam + naamMedewerker + '</td>' + '\n';
```